Brachistochrone Problem. Partial derivatives
I'm trying to solve the brachistochrone problem with a textbook. in the textbook the functional for the problem is derived as follow:

$$ J[y] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx \, F(y, y') \quad\text{with}\quad F(y, y') = \sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2}{b-y}}.\tag{1} $$

original image
This is all clear. Instead of using the Euler-Lagrange equation the textbook suggest a shortcut:

From $F_x = \partial F / \partial x = 0$ the Euler-Lagrange equation follows:
$$ F_{y'}(y, y')y' - F(y, y') = \text{const}. \tag{2}$$

original image
This seems so trivial but i was unable to understand this statement. If someone could provided a short calculation to prove that statement that would be great.

Hi! In the future, please typeset your mathematics using MathJax. Doing so will help keep your answer from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, experienced users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience. ¶ I've taken the step of doing it for you in this instance. Please click [edit] and see what changes I've made and how they work (as well as whether the translation is OK).

Also, it's "brachistochrone" (at least in English it is). Please edit the title and the main body to reflect that. :-)

Also, see the Wikipedia plot summary for the Beltrami identity.

$F_{y'}y' - F$ is constant if and only if its derivative with respect to $x$ vanishes identically.
But
\begin{align*}
\frac d{dx}\big( F_{y'}y' - F\big) &= \frac d{dx}(F_{y'})y' + F_{y'}y'' - \big(F_x + F_yy' + F_{y'}y''\big) \\
&=\big(\frac d{dx}(F_{y'})-F_y\big)y'.
\end{align*}
Assuming $y'\ne 0$ on the appropriate interval, we see that the derivative is $0$ if and only if the Euler-Lagrange equation holds.

Note that OP's Lagrangian $F$ does not depend on the independent variable $x$.

OP's eq. (2) is the Beltrami identity (BI).

The BI can alternatively be viewed as a special case of Noether's theorem: The energy function is conserved along a solution.


